# How would a user who installs my app access variables from the .env file, if it is ignored by git?

Tags: python-3.x, git, google-api, environment-variables, google-oauth

I am new to working with APIs, and I recently started a Python project making use of the Google Calendar API that has been put on github. As such, to protect the API keys I created a .env file and stored the keys as environment variables.

I followed guides that told me to make sure to .gitignore the .env file. However, I don't understand how a user who downloads my app and uses it would be able to access the API key values in the .env file, if the .env file is not in the git repo to begin with.

The values in my .env file are essential to authorizing the user's Google account (via OAuth) for use with the app.
What steps would I take to make sure a user of the app is able to retrieve the variables in the ignored .env file?

Comment: If the file is required for the app to work, it should be added to the repository, not ignored. Unless the user is expected to provide their own version of the file.

Comment: Either your users are supposed to be providing their own environment, or this shouldn't be running on their machines.

Comment: Typically you'd add a `.env.default` which would NOT be ignored, but not used directly to your app. This would contain all available options that can be configured, with some default values. The user would then copy the file to one called `.env` and update it according to their needs.

Comment: @Derek I see, so I would need to provide the values to them somehow, and have them configure it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see, so I would need to provide the values to them somehow, and have them configure it manually?

Yes, but if those values are sensitive, there should not be stored in the Git repository in the first place.
Which means your README (in that git repository) should include instructions in order for a user to:

- fetch those values
- build the env file